# How to Post and insert Data into DB using Laravel, Bootstrap Modal and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Issue is i am not able to get bootstrap modal textarea input value using Input::get(), it returns null.

**Modal's submit and text input(my view):**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="customModalSubmitFunction('modalID')">Submit</button>
```

**JS function:**

```
function customModalSubmitFunction(modalID){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "urlRouteToController"
    });
}
```

**Route.php route**

```
Route::post('urlRouteToController', array(
    'uses' => 'myController@insertValueIntoDatabase',
    'as' => 'urlRouteToController'
));
```

**Controller**

```
public function myController(){
   $dbModel = new Model;
   $dbModel->column1 = Input::get('textbox1');
   $dbModel->save();
}
```

In conclusion, i cannot get posted data using Input::get('textbox1'). But inserting data into database as null values (because i cannot get textbox value) part works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not sending the data with the ajax request.

Comment: @Szenis i tried data: {myData, "urlRouteToController"} too, but in controller i couldn't be able to get posted value using $_POST['myData'] too. That one gave me a null value too.

Comment: You should use the Request class ````use Illuminate\Http\Request;```` place this on top right below the namespace of your controller then in the function ````public function myController(Request $request)```` Then u can try to var dump the request variable to check if you are reciving any data. for more info check http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

Comment: @Szenis i am already checking laravel documents and API, btw using laravel 4.2. There's nothing wrong with including namespaces. But thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller assuming you are adding new users (just for the example).
First I devine the model users in the construct function so that the function called myController can use it in a nice/clean way. Then I am calling to a function within the Model.

```
Use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Use App\Models\Users;

class className extends baseController 
{
    private $users;

    function __construct(Users $users) {
         $this->users = $users;
    }

    public function myController(Request $request) {
        $this->users->createUser($request);
    }
}
```

The model will need to have the exact same name of the table in the database so assuming we have a table called Users our model class will be Users. The variable fillable makes sure only the given fields may changes the is for protecting things like for example a membership status.
The function will create a new record in the database and hash the password of the user.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Users extends Eloquent
{
     protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];

     public function createUser($request) {
          $this->create([
               'username' => $request->username,
               'password' => \Hash::make($request->password)
          ]);
     }
}
```

Then the form needs to have a field with the name username and a field with the name password.
Or if you want to do it with a ajax request you could do it like this be aware that I am using the ID of the input field in this example.

```
function customModalSubmitFunction(modalID){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "urlRouteToController"
        data: {'username' : $('#username').val(), 'password': $('#password').val()}
    });
}
```

I am using laravel 5 so I am not sure this will work correctly but I hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you. Just because of using serialize(), my function wasn't working. Tried .val() and it works like a charm.

Comment: Why can't user serialize for this ? why not explain?

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass data in $.ajax function.

```
function customModalSubmitFunction(modalID){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "urlRouteToController",
        data: $('form-id').serialize(),
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried this one too already. my laravel debugger shows me this query result :
insert into `myTableName` (`myField1`) values ('')
so it still returns a null value.

Comment: in js --> data: {'myData': data}, controller --> Input:get('myData') sould be work

Comment: debugging says that "Cannot read property 'serialize' of null" which means the value hasn't been reached to the javascript function.